# Python 3, Variables in loops

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, variables

I'm new to python, and just playing around, getting to learn different features with this code.(Please read note)

```
less = ["science", "maths"]

for i in range(0,len(less)):
    a = ("You have got; " + (less[i]))
    b = (a)
    #By putting in print here I figured out that it added science first then maths overrides it.
    print(b)

print (b)
```

At the moment when you print the string at the moment it says:

"You have got; maths"

But i was trying to get it to say:

"You have got; science maths"

Basically, i'm trying to find a way to just add to the variable and not one override the other so when i print it at the end it will have both science and maths.

I am going to expand upon it which is why i need to have the length of the list is the loop and etc.

Comment: You're overriding the value of `a` in every iteration, what did you expect? You know how to concatenate strings, surely you can figure this one out?

Comment: If you could just "figure it out" then there would be no point in this website. Two pointless comments imo. The latter is overly complex for someone starting out with Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate simply over objects in the list and make `print` statement not terminate the line.

```
less = ["science", "maths"]

print ("You have got; ", end="")
for i in less:
    print (i, end=" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
less = ["science", "maths"]
print ('You have got; {}'.format(' '.join(less)))
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, use `join`:

```
>>> less = ["science", "maths"]
>>> print("You have got; %s" % ' '.join(less))
You have got; science maths
```

Explanation: `join` joins the elements in the list as a single `string` which you may add at the end of your required string

Comment: Or avoid the string concat and use `print('You have got;', ' '.join(less))`

Comment: Why is it better to not concat the strings but to let print do that?

Comment: Check my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39117991/python-3-variables-in-loops/39118066#39118066 it's because strings are immutable and any next concatenation produces new object in memory.

Comment: The better way would be `print('You have got; {}'.format(' '.join(less)))`

Comment: @syntonym: print does not concatenates the `string`. It just displays them on the screen as that is a single sentence. If you contenate, it will create new object as strings are immutable.

Comment: @syntonym I agree, but you had concatenation before: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39118061/revisions and this was about.